# Cannot delete phantom table using `bq` or BigQuery UI

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to remove a table from a dataset using `bq` without success:

`BigQuery error in rm operation: Not found: Table carbon-web-...:AS_....Orders_01Jun2014_31May2015_3704438_01`

The table is listed whenever I run `bq ls AS_...`.

I'm seeing similar behavior when I try to access the table from the BigQuery UI. When I click on the link to the table, I receive an error message:

`Unable to find table: carbon-web-...:AS_....Orders_01May2017_31May2017`

Is there a way to force a refresh on the metadata for this dataset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are tables in transient state that shouldn't have been exposed. We found a bug in a feature that we were rolling out with listing tables where in some rare scenarios tables in transient state would show up in the list. We have reverted that now.

Comment: It's good to hear that you found the cause of your problem.  You could make your answer more helpful for future readers by explaining *how* you diagnosed it, and in particular, which evidence will identify this problem when it's seen elsewhere.

Comment: @TobySpeight I believe this was a bug with BigQuery and required an update to the service itself.